# Cypher UNION - How to apply to collected lists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider the following use of `UNION` cypher command:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[]-(org:Organization)
WHERE org.size > 100
RETURN collect({
   user.name,
   user.age
}) AS userList

UNION

MATCH (user:User)-[]-(family:Family)
WHERE family.mood = "Happy"
RETURN collect({
   user.name,
   user.age
}) AS userList
```

The `UNION` does not work, this query returns users only from the first `MATCH`. I suspect it's because of the `collect` statements, however the project's design requires the data to be collected. Is there a way to create a union of the collections, or perhaps collect *after* the union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will work just fine except that you should 1) return a valid dictionary format and 2) use CALL which is a subquery for neo4j cypher.

```
RETURN  {
   name: user.name,
   age:  user.age
   } AS userList
```

See sample below:

```
CALL {MATCH (user:user{id:"some_id"}) 
RETURN {
  id: user.id, 
  age: user.age
}  AS userList
UNION
MATCH (user:user{id:"some_id2"}) 
RETURN  {
  id: user.id, 
  age: user.age
}  AS userList
} 
RETURN collect(userList) as userList

 Result:
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"userList"                                                │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"id":"some_id","age":null},{"id":"some_id2","age":null}]│
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I am using neo4j version 4.4.3

Comment: This works for me and does not include dependency on `apoc` - kudos!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apoc.coll.union` of the `APOC` library, to create a union of two lists, like this:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[]-(org:Organization)
WHERE org.size > 100
WITH collect({
   user.name,
   user.age
}) AS userList1
MATCH (user:User)-[]-(family:Family)
WHERE family.mood = "Happy"
WITH userList1, collect({
   user.name,
   user.age
}) AS userList2
RETURN apoc.coll.union(userList1, userList2) AS userList
```

The function `apoc.coll.union` will not include duplicates, if you want to include duplicates use `apoc.coll.unionAll`.

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm this works. I'm however giving the answer to joss_bacoy as his solution does not require `apoc`